# Why can localStorage properties be manipulated directly?

Tags: html

I understand that getters and setters are required in order to manipulate localStorage properties, but the following nevertheless work:

Setting

```
localStorage.name = 'John'
```

Getting

```
var name = localStorage.name
```

Is this because localStorage is a DTO?

Comment: It's recommended but not required to use the methods. In most browsers it's exposed just like any other built-in object, meaning you can use the property keys directly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Awesome, @skyline3000 thank you!